# Touch-sensitive "Overlay" <div> doesn't register swipes after page scrolling

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, google-chrome-extension

I'm designing an extension for Google Chrome, and I'd really like to earn a little cash from it (if possible) so I'm not eager to post the code in its entirety. I hope this isn't a prohibitive limitation for my question.

I'm injecting a content script into all websites as part of my extension, and part of the content script includes a touch-sensitive overlay; it's an invisible HTML div that's been assigned a swipe listener. The idea is to add swiping functionality to every website on which the script is run.

I'm having issues, though, with the overlay seeming to "die" on certain pages, especially after scrolling down the page. It registers swipes flawlessly all across google.com- scrolling or otherwise- but, for example, seems to die on engadget.com after scrolling down the page a bit. (After scrolling a bit more, it often starts registering swipes again.) Doing something like opening the console (F12) also causes it to start registering swipes, and refreshing the page (to the same place the object was before) lets it start registering again.

The HTML/JavaScript I'm utilizing for the overlay is this:

```
$("/<div class = \"touch_sensitive_overlay\" style = \"top:40%;opacity:1;position:fixed;height:247px;z-index:99999;width:50%;left:50%;border:2px solid   black;\"></div>").prependTo('body');"
```

I'm using the jQuery Mobile library to register the swipes.

Any helpful insights would be profoundly appreciated.

---

Update:

A solution was proposed by Sumurai8, and was successfully implemented. The document was listened to for scrolling, and- whenever scrolling occurred- the overlay was removed from the injected HTML, then immediately re-injected. In this way, the overlay is continuously "active," and responds to input on all websites. Thanks for the good thinking, Sumurai8.

Comment: Set z-index to max value 2147483647. `style="z-index: 2147483647"`

Comment: Thanks for the response, Omar. I just edited my original post after realizing that it can't be a placement issue; hence, setting the z-index to its max didn't have any effect. I noticed that by refreshing the page, the overlay suddenly starts working (although still in the same screen position it was in before the refresh), so I'm trying to wrap my brain around the new information.

Comment: Try putting it first thing in the page, using `prepend`. It could be a HTML hierarchy problem. Not sure though. Edit: you're using prepend already. Nevermind =)

Comment: Thanks again, but no luck there either. (I've been prepending it to the body the whole time.) I just did an experiment that yielded some more info, however: if I scroll down the page in *really small increments*, the overlay registers swipes the entire time. If I scroll down in larger increments, it registers only intermittently. Weird!

Comment: You could try to have a small script that does 'something' with the overlay when any element is scrolled. E.g. `$('*').on('scroll', function() { $('#overlay').css( {'top': '0'} ); } );` and see if that fixes the problem. It doesn't sound like a logical problem, but more like Chrome ceasing to render it.

Comment: Problem solved! Directly in keeping with your idea, I had jQuery remove the div upon scrolling, then immediately re-append it to the body. This problem has plagued me for *weeks*! Fantastic call, Sumurai8!!! (Also, I'm new to stackoverflow, and can't find out how to promote your comment as an answer. Am I responsible for doing this, or are there moderators whose job this is? Yours was the solution, and you deserve credit for it.)

Comment: @mscott5861 Promoting a comment is not possible. Comments are not really supposed to be the place to put an answer anyway, but as I didn't have time to properly test it, I didn't feel like posting it as an actual answer. I am glad it helped you and I've posted it as an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to have a small script that does 'something' with the overlay when any element is scrolled. E.g. `$('*').on('scroll', function() { $('#overlay').css( {'top': '0'} ); } );` and see if that fixes the problem. While in itself it doesn't do anything, it might make Chrome render your overlay again.

As you said in the comments, removing the overlay and re-appending it will force Chrome to render it again too.